# Scoundril's Folly: Shadow Golum-Ei: Where did he go in the the East Empire Company Warehouse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In order to solve the quest "Scoundril's Folly" I followed Golum-Ei into the East Empire Company Warehouse. When dealing with guards I lost track of him. Where did he go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow the deck around the edge of the water, on the other side from the entrance, there is a set of steps leading down to the ground below the deck. From down there there is a ramp leading back up to an area behind the shelves full of goods. In the area behind the shelves there is an exit to a smuggler's cave full of bandits. At the end of that cave is Golum-Ei.

Comment: Thanks. When I loaded the game I immedatly saw a quest-pointer which led me to "Brinewater Groto". Seems to have been a glitch.

Comment: @k0pernikus Somewhat, although that's where you would wind up after walking through the warehouse and cave.